# android error view not attached to window manager and crash?

Tags: android, view

when i start my apps my application is force to close and gives error of view not attached to window manager i dont understand what exactly error try to say
i was put my code here with logcat error

> Logcat Error

```
12-19 18:28:06.258: E/WindowManager(5960): Activity com.example.vixxa.HomeActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@419d0390 that was originally added here
12-19 18:28:06.258: E/WindowManager(5960): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.vixxa.HomeActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@419d0390 that was originally added here
12-19 18:28:06.258: E/WindowManager(5960):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:349)
12-19 18:28:06.258: E/WindowManager(5960):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:267)
12-19 18:28:06.258: E/WindowManager(5960):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:215)
12-19 18:28:06.258: E/WindowManager(5960):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:140)
12-19 18:28:06.258: E/WindowManager(5960):  at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:537)
12-19 18:28:06.258: E/WindowManager(5960):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:285)
12-19 18:28:06.258: E/WindowManager(5960):  at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:116)
12-19 18:28:06.258: E/WindowManager(5960):  at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:99)
12-19 18:28:06.258: E/WindowManager(5960):  at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:94)
12-19 18:28:06.258: E/WindowManager(5960):  at com.example.vixxa.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:370)
12-19 18:28:06.258: E/WindowManager(5960):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4492)
12-19 18:28:06.258: E/WindowManager(5960):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
12-19 18:28:06.258: E/WindowManager(5960):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
12-19 18:28:06.258: E/WindowManager(5960):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
12-19 18:28:06.258: E/WindowManager(5960):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3351)
12-19 18:28:06.258: E/WindowManager(5960):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:123)
12-19 18:28:06.258: E/WindowManager(5960):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1151)
12-19 18:28:06.258: E/WindowManager(5960):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-19 18:28:06.258: E/WindowManager(5960):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-19 18:28:06.258: E/WindowManager(5960):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
12-19 18:28:06.258: E/WindowManager(5960):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-19 18:28:06.258: E/WindowManager(5960):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-19 18:28:06.258: E/WindowManager(5960):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
12-19 18:28:06.258: E/WindowManager(5960):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
12-19 18:28:06.258: E/WindowManager(5960):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-19 18:28:06.258: E/wifienabled(5960): wifitrue
```

> HomeActivity.java

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            wifiManager = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
            Log.e("wifienabled","wifi"+wifiManager.isWifiEnabled());


                gps = new GPSTracker(HomeActivity.this);
                // check if GPS enabled
                if(gps.canGetLocation())
                {
                        latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                        longitude = gps.getLongitude();         // \n is for new line
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }


            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build(); 
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 

            alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create(); 
            flightalertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
            loginalertDialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();

            if(CheckConnection.getInstance(this).isOnline(this))
            {
                progressdialogflight = ProgressDialog.show(HomeActivity.this, "Loading...", "Please Wait");


                 int displaymode=getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
                    if(displaymode==1)
                    {
                        policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build(); 
                        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 
                         new FlightListBack().execute("");
                        Log.e("Home", "You are  online!!!!");
                        Toast.makeText(this,"You are online!!!!",2000).show();

                    }
                    else
                    {

                         policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build(); 
                         StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
                         new FlightListBack().execute("");
                        Toast.makeText(this,"You are  online!!!!",2000).show();

                    }

            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(this,"You are not online!!!!",2000).show();
                //alert();
            }


        int displaymode=getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
        if(displaymode==1)
        {
            setContentView(R.layout.homeportrait);

            scrollView =(ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
             scrollView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
             public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event)
            {
                findViewById(R.id.scrollView).getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                Log.e("SCroll View Touch","Work");
                return false;
            }
            });

            ListView lv =getListView();
            lv.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
                {
                    Log.e("ListView","Work");
                                        // Disallow the touch request for parent scroll on touch of child view
                    v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            setContentView(R.layout.home);


            scrollView =(ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrollView);

            scrollView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
             public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event)
            {
                findViewById(R.id.scrollView).getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                Log.e("SCroll View Touch","Work");
                return false;
            }
            });

            ListView lv =getListView();
            lv.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
                {
                    Log.e("ListView","Work");
                                        // Disallow the touch request for parent scroll on touch of child view
                    v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                    return false;
                }
            });



        }


        radiogroupsettings= (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radiogroupsettings);

        editusername=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editusername);
        editpassword=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editpassword);
        headergobutton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.headergobutton);

        imageslider = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageslider);
        imagefacebook_icon=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imagefacebookicon);
        imagetwitter_icon=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imagetwittericon);
        imageyoutube_icon=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageyoutubeicon);

        imageappsheader=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageappsheader);
        imagevisitor = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imagevisitor);
        imagerestaurant =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imagerestaurant);
        imageclubs =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageclubs);
        imagespa =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imagespa);
        imagedeals=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imagedeals);
        imageshopping=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageshopping);
        imagemagazine=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imagemagazine);
        imageairport =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageairport);
        imageairport.setOnClickListener(this);
        imagehotel =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imagehotel);
        imagecategory=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imagecategory);
        imagecarrental=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imagecarrental);
        imagestation =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imagestation);

        imagefooter=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imagefooter);

        DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);

        height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
        width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;

        headergobutton.setOnClickListener(this);

        imagegooglesearch=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imagegooglesearch);
        imagegooglesearch.setOnClickListener(this);

        imageyahoo=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageyahoo);
        imageyahoo.setOnClickListener(this);

        imageespn=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageespn);
        imageespn.setOnClickListener(this);

        imageamazon=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageamazon);
        imageamazon.setOnClickListener(this);

        imageyoutube=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageyoutube);
        imageyoutube.setOnClickListener(this);

        imagenetflix=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imagenetflix);
        imagenetflix.setOnClickListener(this);

        imagehulu=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imagehulu);
        imagehulu.setOnClickListener(this);

        imagelive365=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imagelive365);
        imagelive365.setOnClickListener(this);

        imagefacebook=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imagefacebook);
        imagefacebook.setOnClickListener(this);

        imageskype=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageskype);
        imageskype.setOnClickListener(this);

        imagegames=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imagegames);
        imagegames.setOnClickListener(this);

        imagewifi=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imagewifi);
        imagewifi.setOnClickListener(this);

     //   buttontime=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttontime);
     //  buttontime.setOnClickListener(this);
        // user layout textview in android

        textviewcity=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textviewcity);
        textviewinfo=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textviewinfo);
        textviewairport=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textviewairport);

        text1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);
        text2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text2);
        text3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text3);
        text4=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text4);
        text5=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text5);
        text6=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text6);


        //********** For Image Slide Image automatically Change *****************************

        final int []sliderImageArray={R.drawable.banner,R.drawable.banner01,R.drawable.banner02};
        final int []footerImageArray={R.drawable.bottomadv,R.drawable.sandwich,R.drawable.underbig};
        try 
        {

            Log.e("Land Scape Run","");
            Log.e("LandScape  Run","Handler ");
                final Handler imagehandler = new Handler();

                Runnable runnable;

                runnable = new Runnable()
                {

                    int i=0;
                    public void run()
                    {   // slider image run
                        imageslider.setImageResource(sliderImageArray[i]);  //Log.e("Image Run",""+sliderImageArray[i]);
                        i++;
                        if(i>sliderImageArray.length-1)
                        {
                                i=0;    
                                clear();
                        }
                        imagehandler.postDelayed(this, 4000); // for interval
                    }

                };
                imagehandler.postDelayed(runnable,10);

                final Handler footerimagehandler =new Handler();
                runnable = new Runnable()
                {   
                    int j=0;
                    public void run()
                    {   // footer image run
                        imagefooter.setImageResource(footerImageArray[j]); //   Log.e("Image Run",""+footerImageArray[j]);
                        j++;
                        if(j>footerImageArray.length-1)
                        {
                                j=0;    
                                clear();
                        }
                        footerimagehandler.postDelayed(this, 5000); // for interval
                    }
                };

                footerimagehandler.postDelayed(runnable, 10);


                // For ListView Change after 10 seconds;

                final Handler departurehandler =new Handler();
                runnable = new Runnable()
                {   

                    public void run()
                    {   

                        if(CheckConnection.getInstance(HomeActivity.this).isOnline(HomeActivity.this))
                        {

                                if(cheklist==0)
                                {   
                                                //Log.e("departure before chek List", "chek-->"+cheklist);
                                                 cheklist=1;
                                                // Log.e("departure  after chek List", "chek-->"+cheklist);
                                                if(!flightList.isEmpty())
                                                {

                                                                Log.e("listhandler departure","work");
                                                                int displaymode=getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
                                                                if(displaymode==1)
                                                                {

                                                                        text1.setText("Destination");
                                                                        text4.setText("Schedule");
                                                                        textviewcity.setText(textcity);
                                                                        textviewairport.setText(textairport);
                                                                        textviewinfo.setText("Departure Flight List");

                                                                        ListAdapter departureadapter = new SimpleAdapter(HomeActivity.this,flightList,
                                                                                R.layout.listportrait,
                                                                                new String[] { TAG_MDESTINATION, TAG_MFLIGHT, TAG_MAIRLINE,TAG_MSCHEDULE,TAG_MTERMINALGATE,TAG_MFSTATUS  }, new int[] {
                                                                                        R.id.textdestination, R.id.textflight, R.id.textairline,R.id.textschedule,R.id.texttermgate,R.id.textstatus });
                                                                        setListAdapter(departureadapter);

                                                                }
                                                                else
                                                                {
                                                                            text1.setText("Destination");
                                                                            text4.setText("Schedule");  
                                                                           textviewcity.setText(textcity);
                                                                           textviewairport.setText(textairport);
                                                                           textviewinfo.setText("Departure Flight List");

                                                                        ListAdapter departureadapter = new SimpleAdapter(HomeActivity.this,flightList,
                                                                                R.layout.list,
                                                                                new String[] { TAG_MDESTINATION, TAG_MFLIGHT, TAG_MAIRLINE,TAG_MSCHEDULE,TAG_MTERMINALGATE,TAG_MFSTATUS  }, new int[] {
                                                                                        R.id.textdestination, R.id.textflight, R.id.textairline,R.id.textschedule,R.id.texttermgate,R.id.textstatus });
                                                                        setListAdapter(departureadapter);

                                                                  }
                                            } // for interval
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {   
                                        //Log.e("departure before chek List", "chek-->"+cheklist);
                                                cheklist=0;
                                        //Log.e("departure after List", "chek-->"+cheklist);        
                                                if(!arrivalList.isEmpty())
                                                {
                                                                Log.e("listhandler arrival","work");
                                                                    int displaymode=getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
                                                                    if(displaymode==1)
                                                                    {
                                                                        text1.setText("Origin");
                                                                        text4.setText("Arrival");
                                                                        textviewinfo.setText("Arrival Flight List");

                                                                            ListAdapter arrivaladapter = new SimpleAdapter(HomeActivity.this,arrivalList,
                                                                                    R.layout.listportrait,
                                                                                    new String[] { TAG_MDESTINATION, TAG_MFLIGHT, TAG_MAIRLINE,TAG_MSCHEDULE,TAG_MTERMINALGATE,TAG_MFSTATUS  }, new int[] {
                                                                                            R.id.textdestination, R.id.textflight, R.id.textairline,R.id.textschedule,R.id.texttermgate,R.id.textstatus });
                                                                            setListAdapter(arrivaladapter);

                                                                    }
                                                                    else
                                                                    {
                                                                            text1.setText("Origin");
                                                                            text4.setText("Arrival");
                                                                            textviewinfo.setText("Arrival Flight List");

                                                                        ListAdapter arrivaladapter = new SimpleAdapter(HomeActivity.this,arrivalList,
                                                                                R.layout.list,
                                                                                new String[] { TAG_MDESTINATION, TAG_MFLIGHT, TAG_MAIRLINE,TAG_MSCHEDULE,TAG_MTERMINALGATE,TAG_MFSTATUS  }, new int[] {
                                                                                        R.id.textdestination, R.id.textflight, R.id.textairline,R.id.textschedule,R.id.texttermgate,R.id.textstatus });
                                                                        setListAdapter(arrivaladapter);

                                                                    }
                                                } 
                                    }

                        }                               
                        else
                        {

                            if(alertDialog.isShowing())
                            {   
                                alertDialog.dismiss();
                            }
                            else
                            {

                                alert();
                            }

                            scrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);

                        }


                        departurehandler.postDelayed(this, 10000);
                    }

                };  departurehandler.postDelayed(runnable, 100);




        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below is causing your application to force close

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build(); 
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

The thing is you are trying to call web service from the main thread which is against the android thread policy.

So due to this StrictMode.ThreadPolicy will force close your application. 

So please check after commenting the code related to strictmode and then try to run once again.